# Tether USDT signup not avaible and its erc20 no transaction

Tags: tokens

I checked usdt, the company tether tether.to disabled its signup function, and I cannot signup for API. and I also checked the ERC20 usdt token, it looks like almost one year no transaction. 
Do you think tether API and USDT normal now?